# Scroll wheel not working properly on Fedora 39

Tags: fedora, wayland

I am running Fedora 39 on a Dell Laptop with external Microsoft Sculpt Ergonomic Keyboard and Mouse.  The mouse has a scroller but on all programs--Firefox, Document Viewer, Eclipse IDE--the mouse doesn't either respond at all, or only scrolls once or twice.  I have an older machine with Ubuntu Mate 23.10 and I don't face the same issue with the same mouse.

I am not a power user, and I am wondering if there is a command line option available to resolve this issue with Fedora 39 + Wayland.  Thank you.

## System Details Report

---

### Report details

- **Date generated:**                              2024-02-17 22:33:43

### Hardware Information:

- **Hardware Model:**                              Dell Inc. Inspiron 3781
- **Memory:**                                      8.0 GiB
- **Processor:**                                   Intel® Core™ i3-7020U × 4
- **Graphics:**                                    Intel® HD Graphics 620 (KBL GT2F)
- **Disk Capacity:**                               1.0 TB

### Software Information:

- **Firmware Version:**                            1.24.0
- **OS Name:**                                     Fedora Linux 39 (Workstation Edition)
- **OS Build:**                                    (null)
- **OS Type:**                                     64-bit
- **GNOME Version:**                               45.4
- **Windowing System:**                            Wayland
- **Kernel Version:**                              Linux 6.7.4-200.fc39.x86_64

Comment: I would ask you to type lsusb at your shell prompt and show what it displays.
It shows all usb ports and what is plugged into it.

Comment: Hi Oppie, thank you for responding.  Here's the output that I see when I run the command:

Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub  
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 045e:07a5 Microsoft Corp. Wireless Receiver 1461C  
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1bcf:2b98 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc.  Integrated_Webcam_HD  
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller  
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0cf3:e009 Qualcomm Atheros Communications   
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub